# .f95 programme for seismic absorption band - debugging

Tags: fortran

I am trying to write a programme to calculate an absorption band model for seismic waves. The whole calculation is based on 3 equations. If interested, see equations 3, 4, 5 on p.2 here: 
http://www.eri.u-tokyo.ac.jp/people/takeuchi/publications/14EPSL-Iritani.pdf

However, I have debugged this programme several times now but I do not seem to get the expected answer. I am specifically trying to calculate Q_1 variable (seismic attenuation) in the following programme, which should be a REAL positive value on the order of 10^-3. However, I am getting negative values. I need a fresh pair of eyes to take a look at the programme and to check where I have done a mistake if any. Could someone please check? Many thanks !

```
PROGRAM absorp

! Calculate an absorption band model and output
! files for plotting. 
! Ref. Iritani et al. (2014), EPSL, 405, 231-243.

! Variable Definition
! Corners - cf1, cf2
! Frequency range - [10^f_strt, 10^(f_end-f_strt)]
! Number of points to be sampled - n
! Angular frequency - w
! Frequency dependent Attenuation 1/Q - Q_1
! Relaxation times - tau1=1/(2*pi*cf1), tau2=1/(2*pi*cf2) 
! Reference velocity - V0 (km/s)
! Attenuation (1/Q) at 1 Hz - Q1_1
! Frequency dependent peak Attenuation (1/Qm) - Qm_1
! Frequency dependent velocity - V_w
! D(omega) numerator - Dw1
! D(omega) denominator - Dw2
! D(omega) - D_w
! D(2pi) - D_2pi

IMPLICIT NONE
REAL ::   cf1 = 2.0e0, cf2 = 1.0e+5
REAL, PARAMETER :: f_strt=-5, f_end=12
INTEGER :: indx
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: n=1e3
REAL, PARAMETER :: pi=4.0*atan(1.0)
REAL, DIMENSION(1:n) :: w, Q_1 
REAL  :: tau1, tau2, V0, freq, pow
REAL :: Q1_1=0.003, Qm_1
COMPLEX, DIMENSION(1:n) :: V_w
COMPLEX, PARAMETER :: i=(0.0,1.0)
COMPLEX :: D_2pi, D_w, Dw1, Dw2

! Reference Velocity km/s
V0 = 12.0
print *, "F1=", cf1, "F2=", cf2, "V0=",V0

! Relaxation times from corners
tau1 = 1.0/(2.0*pi*cf1)
tau2 = 1.0/(2.0*pi*cf2)
PRINT*, "tau1=",tau1, "tau2=",tau2

! Populate angular frequency array (non-linear)
DO indx = 1,n+1
pow = f_strt + f_end*REAL(indx-1)/n
freq=10**pow
w(indx) = 2*pi*freq
print *, w(indx)
END DO

! D(2pi) value
D_2pi = LOG((i*2.0*pi + 1/tau1)/(i*2.0*pi + 1/tau2))

! Calculate 1/Q from eq. 3 and 4
DO indx=1,n

!D(omega)
Dw1 = (i*w(indx) + 1.0/tau1)
Dw2 = (i*w(indx) + 1.0/tau2)
D_w  = LOG(Dw1/Dw2)

!This is eq. 5 for 1/Qm
Qm_1 = 2.0*pi*Q1_1*IMAG(D_w)/                 &
     ((Q1_1**2-4)*IMAG(D_w)**2              &
       + 4*Q1_1*IMAG(D_w)*REAL(D_w))

!This is eq. 3 for Alpha(omega)
V_w(indx) = V0*(SQRT(1.0 + 2.0/pi*Qm_1*D_w)/       &
          REAL(SQRT(1.0 + 2.0/pi*Qm_1*D_2pi)))

!This is eq. 4 for 1/Q
Q_1(indx) = 2*IMAG(V_w(indx))/REAL(V_w(indx))

PRINT *, w(indx)/(2.0*pi), (V_w(indx)), Q_1(indx)
END DO

! write the results out
100 FORMAT(F12.3,3X,F7.3,3X,F8.5)
OPEN(UNIT=1, FILE='absorp.txt', STATUS='replace')

DO indx=1,n
WRITE(UNIT=1,FMT=100), w(indx)/(2.0*pi), REAL(V_w(indx)), Q_1(indx)
END DO
CLOSE(UNIT=1)

END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Do not use version tags alone. Use the in addition to the `fortran` tag if the question is version specific (this does not look like us such).

Answer (score 0):

More of an extended comment with formatting than an answer ...

I haven't checked the equations you refer to, and I'm not going to, but looking at your code makes me suspect misplaced brackets as a likely cause of errors.  The code, certainly as you've shown it here, isn't well formatted to reveal its logical structure.  Whatever you do next invest in some indents and some longer lines to avoid breaking too frequently.

Personally I'm suspicious in particular of

```
!This is eq. 5 for 1/Qm
Qm_1 = 2.0*pi*Q1_1*IMAG(D_w)/                 &
     ((Q1_1**2-4)*IMAG(D_w)**2              &
       + 4*Q1_1*IMAG(D_w)*REAL(D_w))
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to be the issue. I have a feeling it's the D_w parameter but not sure what it is.